# How to force images to be aligned in the same line?

Tags: html, css

It's easy to explain with images, here is what I want: [like Google Play, the image could be viewed in a scrolling box!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GzWZ.jpg)
But what I get when I put it into  tag is like this:
[image: My result]

My code:

```
<div style="overflow: scroll; display: inline-block;">
<a class="lightview" title="image1" href="http://1.png" rel="lightbox">
<a class="lightview" title="image2" href="http://2.png" rel="lightbox">
<a class="lightview" title="image3" href="http://3.png" rel="lightbox">
</div>
```

Comment: Note that `</a>` ending tags are mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify that the text will never wrap:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eatgvvje/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

you need to restrict the height of your containing div to be the height of the images.